# Laravel - Change default value eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-migrations

Is possible to modify the default value response from Laravel Eloquent?

I have an API and my database has a migration `payment`.
My payment has a column integer `status`.

```php
$table->integer('status')->default(1);
```

I want to know if is possible to change the default value with any function to change the `Payment->get()` response.

For example:

```php
public static $status = [
    1 => "Waiting for payment",
    2 => "In review",
    3 => "Payed",    
];
```

And automatically call my function:

```php
class Payment extends Model
{
  // ...
  public getStatus() {
    $this->status = $status[$this->status];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost; you can change `getStatus()` to `getStatusAttribute()`, which is a Laravel Accessor, then simply call:

```
$payment = Payment::first();
dd($payment->status);
// Or
$payments = Payment::get();
foreach($payments AS $payment){
  dd($payment->status);
}
```

Instead of outputting `1`, `2`, etc. this will override the value to `'Waiting for payment'`, `'In review'`, etc.

See https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor for full details.

Comment: My question was your first answer:
``/**
     * Get the payment status.
     *
     * @param  int  $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function getStatusAttribute($value)
    {
        return Payment::$status[$value];
    }
``